# Observable vs. Service in Android

Tags: android, service, observable, rx-android

I want to migrate from Android API means of asynchronous execution to Rx. Particularly I have a photo gallery in my application which frequently fetches new photos from a server as the user swipes the photos (it's based on ViewPager with lateral swiping).

It happened like this: whenever the `ViewPager` wanted a new photo it asked its presenter (in MVP terms) to fetch it which in turn went to the model. The model sent a new intent to an `IntentService` to download the new image:
[image: How it worked with IntentService]

Now it looks another way:[image: How it works now, with Rx]

In case of `IntentService` if we have a lot of requests to download an image these requests are queued in a single `IntentService` and processed one at a time.

With Rx many requests to download an image yield many `Observable`s and perhaps consume a lot of memory (I haven't completed refactoring to Rx yet and hence haven't made experiments but probably someone already thought about it).

Am I right in my misgiving? Is there a better way to do the same thing with RxAndroid?

Comment: What solution did you eventually use and why?

Comment: As for resource consumption I don't think there's a big problem with Observables. These are light weighting objects encapsulating data generation/retrieval and modification. Of course, if every observable spawns a new thread, that will lead to huge resource consumption. But if you wisely use thread pools (e.g. Schedulers.io(), Schedulers.computation(), etc.) everything should be fine.

Comment: And Services can not be thought of as something which can be replaced with Observables. Service - is a fundamental Android component. It's a big self contained part of your app (even though it does not have a UI other than notifications). E.g. you can launch it in a separate process and the service will live even if all your Activities are swiped out of RAM. Music players work this way.